# How to go to .pdf from source in Texshop

Tags: pdf, texshop, forward-inverse-search

From the .pdf I can press 'command' click to take me to the source code. But the same does not work when trying to go from source code to .pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight the text you are interested in, right-click, and press "sync"

[image]

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: I have those preferences. And I just downloaded it today after I got my new mac yesterday.

Comment: I have Monterey.

Comment: @pmac From TeXShop's homepage: "TeXShop (v 4.68) Release 10/07/2021
(for Intel and Arm, Sierra through Big Sur)". So you might just need to wait until the next release to fix any Monterey issues.